# Enumerating RCData resources from the EXE file which has been launched

Tags: delphi

I am running Delphi XE6.

I recently integrated all of my read-only language INI files into the executables.

As a consequence, I need to enumerate RCData resources (and then simply filter out the languages).

I stumbled across [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837439/1997354), which I lightly changed into this form:

```
function EnumRCDataProc(hModule: HMODULE; lpszType, lpszName: PChar; lParam: NativeInt): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  TStrings(lParam).Add(lpszName);
  Result := True;
end;

function EnumerateResourceNames: string;

var
  ExecutableHandle: HMODULE;
  ResourcesList: TStringList;

begin
  ExecutableHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(Application.ExeName));
  try
    ResourcesList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      EnumResourceNames(ExecutableHandle, RT_RCDATA, @EnumRCDataProc, NativeInt(ResourcesList));
      Result := ResourcesList.Text;
    finally
      ResourcesList.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(ExecutableHandle);
  end;
end;
```

It is indeed working. Do you see any possible problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is mostly fine but there a couple of minor issues:

- The documentation for `EnumResNameProc` explains that `lpszType` and `lpszName` could be IDs rather than strings. Use the helper function `Is_IntResource` from the `Windows` unit to identify such IDs and treat accordingly.
- Using `LoadLibrary` is fine, but it will result in code in the DLL being executed. Instead you are better to use `LoadLibraryEx` passing the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE or LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` for the flags.

Comment: Well, if the function returns `True` then you don't have a pointer, but it's an ordinal value in the range 0..65535.  If you want to present that as a string do it like this: `'#' + IntToStr(Word(lpszName))` or `'#' + IntToStr(NativeUInt(lpszName))`if you don't want to hard code assumptions about the valid range of ID res values. Not that they could ever ever be changed.